# Going n folders up with a terminal command?

Tags: cd

`cd ..` goes one folder up.

Is there a (one-line) command to go n folders up?

Comment: I usually use `cd ../..` or `cd ../../..`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can define a function to do that:

```
$ go_up() { for i in $(seq $1); do cd ..; done }
$ go_up 3 # go 3 directories up
```

Comment: I accept it as the first and exact answer to the question. I added to my `.bash_profile` both your answer and Jens' `up2` and `up3` (and not even `up4`). As of now, it seems that the later is more practical.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any command that does that, but it is easy to create one yourself. For example, just add

```
cdn() {
  for ((i=0;i<${1-0};i++))
  do
    cd ..
  done
}
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file, and after you create a new shell you can just run

```
cdn N
```

and you will move up by `N` directories

Comment: I see. So the short answer is, "there is nothing built in, write a script for yourself".

Answer (score 3):

All right, another really funny answer, that is *really* a one-liner, to go up 42 parent directories:

```
cd $(yes ../|head -42|tr -d \\n)
```

Same as gniourf_gniourf's other answer, it's `cd -` friendly (and it's just a couple characters longer than the shortest answer).

Replace `42` with your favorite number.

---

Now that you understood the amazing power of the wonderful command `yes`, you can join the dark side and use the evil command `eval`, and while we're at it we can use the terrible backticks:

```
eval `yes 'cd ..;'|head -42`
```

This is so far the shortest one-liner, but it's really bad: it uses `eval`, backticks and it's not `cd -` friendly. But hey, it works really well and it's funny!

Answer (score 2):

you can use a singleline `for` loop:..

```
for i in {1..3}; do cd ../; done
```

replace the `3` with your `n`

for example:

```
m@mariachi:~/test/5/4/3/2/1$ pwd
/home/m/test/5/4/3/2/1

m@mariachi:~/test/5/4/3/2/1$ for i in {1..3}; do cd ../; done

m@mariachi:~/test/5/4$ pwd
/home/m/test/5/4
```

...however I don't think it will be much faster than typing `cd` and  `..` then hitting `tab` for each level you want to go up!!  :)

Answer (score 2):

How often do you go up more than five levels? If the answer is *Not too often* I suggest you place these `cd -` friendly aliases in your profile:

```
alias up2='cd ../..'
alias up3='cd ../../..'
alias up4='cd ../../../..'
alias up5='cd ../../../../..'
```

Advantages

- No bashims, no zshisms, no kshisms.
- Works with any shell supporting aliases
- As readable and understandable as it gets.

Comment: Usually 2-3 levels... A good point with a usecase of _not_ using loops for a situation when "n" won't be big.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Exactly; sophisticated compilers even use it and engineers have invented a word for it: **loop unrolling**.

Comment: I added to my `.bash_profile` `up2` and `up3` along with `goup()` from   @LevLevitsky post. I will see which one I will use in practice (if any :)).

Answer (score 1):

A funny way:

```
cdupn() {
    local a
    [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && printf -v a "%$1s" && cd "${a// /../}"
}
```

How does it work?

- We first check that the argument is indeed a number (a chain of digits).
- We populate the variable `a` with `$1` spaces.
- We perform the `cd` where each space in `a` has been replaced with `../`.

Use as:

```
cdupn 42
```

to go up to forty-second parent directory.

The *pro* of this method is that you'll still be able to `cd -` to come back to previous directory, unlike the methods that use a loop.

Absolutely worth putting in your `.bashrc`. Or not.