# Is there a way to implement bash functions that take in no args but vary based on the length of the name?

Tags: bash

In my travels around my filesystem, I find it's been a good idea to have shortcuts for `cd ..`. As such, I've added a few lines to my .bashrc:

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."
alias ....="cd ../../.."
```

So the pattern is after the first dot, the number of trailing dots is the number of directories back up the hierarchy to climb. I'd like to make it extensible, ideally with a function or something, so that I could type `$ ......` and have it take me to `cd ../../../../..`. Is such a thing possible? Or should I just keep adding lines to my .bashrc to cover as much ground as i think i would want to traverse back in a single go?

Comment: You can have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381145/going-n-folders-up-with-a-terminal-command/17381806

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a function rather than an alias. While a shell function is running, `${FUNCNAME[0]}` contains the name of the function.

```
whatsyourname() {
    echo "I am ${FUNCNAME[0]}"
}
```

But I don't see the point of this. You still have to define all the separate aliases or functions with this definition. There's no way to say "Any command that's just a bunch of dots should run this function" and have it count the dots.

Why not define a function `up` that takes an argument, which is the number of levels to go up? So `up 3` would do `cd ../../..`.

Comment: You could use the `command_not_found_handle` to parse the undefined command into the correct number of directories, but I agree something like `up 3` is much simpler and easier to implement.

Comment: I was pretty sure there wasn't a way to do exactly what I wanted, but thanks for confirming this for me.

Comment: but you should consider using the directory stack that helps you cd into a previous directory (e.g. `cd -`, `cd -2`...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want exactly, but it would be pretty trivial to implement a script which could be called like: `up ...(arbitrary number of .'s)...`.

What you're really asking for is a way to make BASH call a single function when you enter any number of `.`'s > 2. This seems like a "wildcard function name" or something, which I do not believe is possible.

Comment: Keep in mind that `.` is already a POSIX-defined built-in command.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
cd_func() {
    builtin cd "$(echo "$1" \
    | sed -e ':a
              s@\.\.\.@../..@g
              t a')"
}

alias cd=cd_func
```

Then `cd ...` is the same as `cd ../..`, `cd ....` is the same as `cd ../../..`, and so on, as many dots as you want. You can even `cd ..../foo/bar` to move around quickly.

This worked anywhere on the command line back in the DOS days. `cd`, `dir`, and all the programs all treated any sequence of `n` dots referred to the folder `n` levels up in the hierarchy. It was great but with Windows XP and the new `cmd.exe` it stopped working…